# How root motion handle obstacles?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, unreal-engine4

I'm learning about root motion recently. I know that root motion is to use animation to drive the movement of character capsule (collider). The idea is that to extract the transform of a root bone for root motion and apply it to the transform of character capsule.

However, assuming that there are obstacles in the scene and blocking the character capsule, the character capsule is now influenced by both physics (collision) and animation (root motion).

I'm confused about how root motion handle both influence from physics and animation to make the character capsule act correctly.

Comment: Why is this tagged as both [tag:unity3d] **and** [tag:unreal-engine4]?

Answer (score 1):

Root motion changes `transform.position`. It completely ignores obstacles.

You are likely to see jittery motion near obstacles since root motion and physics will be in conflict as root motion takes you into obstacles and physics tries to prevent that.

I would avoid using root motion and recreate it in code with whatever motion method you're using (RigidBody, CharacterController, etc).

[Here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/collisions-with-root-animation-movement.153556/) is also a forum post about this.

Comment: Not only the jittery motion, but overlapping of colliders may occur. I know it's better to implement the movement logic by myself to carefully set the position to avoid jittery motion and overlapping. UE4 implements this kind of logic of root motion and movements inside the engine. It's lucky that UE4 is open source.